# How to update column based on a condition (a value in a group)?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have the following df:

```
+---+----+-----+
|sno|dept|color|
+---+----+-----+
|  1|  fn|  red|
|  2|  fn| blue|
|  3|  fn|green|
+---+----+-----+
```

If any of the color column values is `red`, then I all values of the color column should be updated to be `red`, as below:

```
+---+----+-----+
|sno|dept|color|
+---+----+-----+
|  1|  fn|  red|
|  2|  fn|  red|
|  3|  fn|  red|
+---+----+-----+
```

I could not figure it out. Please help; I have tried following code:

```
val gp=jdbcDF.filter($"dept".contains("fn"))
     //.withColumn("newone",when($"dept"==="fn","RED").otherwise("NULL"))
    gp.show()
gp.map(
  row=>{
    val row1=row.getAs[String](1)
    var row2=row.getAs[String](2)
    val make=if(row1 =="fn") row2="red"
    Row(row(0),row(1),make)
  }
).collect().foreach(println)
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Given:

```
val df = Seq(
  (1, "fn", "red"),
  (2, "fn", "blue"),
  (3, "fn", "green"),
  (4, "aa", "blue"),
  (5, "aa", "green"),
  (6, "bb", "red"),
  (7, "bb", "red"),
  (8, "aa", "blue")
).toDF("id", "fn", "color")
```

Do the calculation:

```
val redOrNot = df.groupBy("fn")
  .agg(collect_set('color) as "values")
  .withColumn("hasRed", array_contains('values, "red"))

// gives null for no option
val colorPicker = when('hasRed, "red")
val result = df.join(redOrNot, "fn")
  .withColumn("resultColor", colorPicker) 
  .withColumn("color", coalesce('resultColor, 'color)) // skips nulls that leads to the answer
  .select('id, 'fn, 'color)
```

The `result` looks as follows (that seems to be an answer):

```
scala> result.show
+---+---+-----+
| id| fn|color|
+---+---+-----+
|  1| fn|  red|
|  2| fn|  red|
|  3| fn|  red|
|  4| aa| blue|
|  5| aa|green|
|  6| bb|  red|
|  7| bb|  red|
|  8| aa| blue|
+---+---+-----+
```

You can chain `when` operators and have a default value with `otherwise`. Consult the [scaladoc of `when` operator](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.functions$@when(condition:org.apache.spark.sql.Column,value:Any):org.apache.spark.sql.Column).

I think you could do something very similar (and perhaps more efficient) using windowed operators or user-defined aggregate functions (UDAF), but...well...don't currently know how to do it. Leaving the comment here to inspire others ;-)

p.s. Learnt a lot! Thanks for the idea!

Comment: I hope i can replace when with UDF, so i can return any color based on some logic.

Comment: See the update. You should be careful with a UDF as Spark SQL's query optimizer might do poor(er) optimization.

Comment: @Shankar: this kind of syntax is possible `df.withColumn("Green_Ind", when($"color" === "Green", 1).when($"color" === "Red", 1).otherwise(0))`

Comment: @JacekLaskowski: What about window functions. Although your answer is best,  I think it can also be achieved with Window functions isnt it?

Comment: @JacekLaskowski: Still wondering, is it not possible to achieve this without `join`, what if the data is huge, yes it is possible to use broadcast join for first DF though.

Answer (score 10):

Efficient solution which doesn't require expensive grouping:

```
// All groups with `red`
df.where($"color" === "red").select($"fn".alias("fn_")).distinct
  // Join with input
  .join(df.as("df"), $"fn" === $"fn_", "rightouter")
  // Replace `color`
  .withColumn("color", when($"fn_"isNull, $"color").otherwise(lit("red")))
  .drop("fn_")
```

Comment: This a great answer. Jacek also mentions it in the accepted answer.

Answer (score 5):

You are conditionally updating the DataFrame if it satisfies a certain property. In this case the property is "the color column contains 'red'".  The idiomatic way to express this is to filter with the desired predicate and then determine whether any rows satisfy it. There is no need for a join.

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.lit
import org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame

def makeAllRedIfAnyAreRed(df: DataFrame) = {
    val containsRed = df.filter(df("color") === "red").count() > 0
    if (containsRed) df.withColumn("color", lit("red")) else df
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Spark 2.2.0:
Sample Dataframe ( taken from above examples)

```
    val df = Seq(
  (1, "fn", "red"),
  (2, "fn", "blue"),
  (3, "fn", "green"),
  (4, "aa", "blue"),
  (5, "aa", "green"),
  (6, "bb", "red"),
  (7, "bb", "red"),
  (8, "aa", "blue")
).toDF("id", "dept", "color")
```

created a UDF to perform the update by checking the condition.

```
val replace_val = udf((x: String,y:String) => if (Option(x).getOrElse("").equalsIgnoreCase("fn")&&(!y.equalsIgnoreCase("red"))) "red" else y)

val final_df = df.withColumn("color", replace_val($"dept",$"color"))
final_df.show()
```

output:

[image]

spark 1.6:

```
val conf = new SparkConf().setMaster("local").setAppName("My app")
val sc = new SparkContext(conf)
val sqlContext = new SQLContext(sc)

import sqlContext.implicits._
// For implicit conversions like converting RDDs to DataFrames
val df = sc.parallelize(Seq(
  (1, "fn", "red"),
  (2, "fn", "blue"),
  (3, "fn", "green"),
  (4, "aa", "blue"),
  (5, "aa", "green"),
  (6, "bb", "red"),
  (7, "bb", "red"),
  (8, "aa", "blue")
) ).toDF("id","dept","color")


val replace_val = udf((x: String,y:String) => if (Option(x).getOrElse("").equalsIgnoreCase("fn")&&(!y.equalsIgnoreCase("red"))) "red" else y)
val final_df = df.withColumn("color", replace_val($"dept",$"color"))

final_df.show()
```

Answer (score 2):

As there could be few rows in filtered dataframe I'm adding solution with `isin()` and `.withColumn()` combination.

Sample DataFrame

```
val df = Seq(
  (1, "fn", "red"),
  (2, "fn", "blue"),
  (3, "fn", "green"),
  (4, "aa", "blue"),
  (5, "aa", "green"),
  (6, "bb", "red"),
  (7, "bb", "red"),
  (8, "aa", "blue")
).toDF("id", "dept", "color")
```

Now Let's pick only `dept`s which have at least one **red** `color` row and place it in `broadcast` variable like below.

```
val depts = sc.broadcast(df.filter($"color" === "red").select(collect_set("dept")).first.getSeq[String](0)))
```

Update **red** color for filtered `depts` records.

> `isin()` takes a vararg so convert list to vararg (`depts.value:_*`)

```
//creating new column by giving diff name (clr) to see the diff
val result = df.withColumn("clr", when($"dept".isin(depts.value:_*),lit("red"))
                    .otherwise($"color"))

result.show()

+---+----+-----+-----+
| id|dept|color|  clr|
+---+----+-----+-----+
|  1|  fn|  red|  red|
|  2|  fn| blue|  red|
|  3|  fn|green|  red|
|  4|  aa| blue| blue|
|  5|  aa|green|green|
|  6|  bb|  red|  red|
|  7|  bb|  red|  red|
|  8|  aa| blue| blue|
+---+----+-----+-----+
```