# Avoid Group By in JavaPairRDD Apache Spark

Tags: java, apache-spark

I have rewritten this code in in Spark using JavaRDD. I read that groupByKey is costly operation.

Can we rewrite this by avoiding the groupByKey.

After grouping by key, I am trying to update the values of for the key if applicable.

Can some one help

```
    List<Items> items = getItems();
    Map<String, List<ItemId>> itemsByName = items.stream()
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(ItemId::getName, Collectors.toList()));

    List<ItemId> newItems = itemsByName.entrySet().stream()
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(e -> e.getKey(), e -> {
            //update values if applicable
                List<ItemId> rps = e.getValue().stream().filter(s -> s.isApplicable()).collect(Collectors.toList());
                return rps.isEmpty() ? e.getValue() : rps;
            }))
            .values().stream()
            .flatMap(x -> x.stream()).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

JavaRDD

```
    JavaRDD<Items> items = getItemsRDD();
    JavaPairRDD<String, ItemId> itemsByName = 
            items.mapToPair(e -> new Tuple2<String, ItemId>(e.getName(), e));

    JavaRDD<ItemId> newItems= itemsByName.groupByKey().mapValues(x->{
        //update values if applicable
        List<ItemId> e = new ArrayList<>();
        x.iterator().forEachRemaining(e::add);
        List<ItemId> rps = e.stream().filter(s -> s.isApplicable()).collect(Collectors.toList());
        return rps.isEmpty() ? e: rps;
     }).flatMap(x->x._2);
```

I am trying to do some thing similar but in java
[How to update column based on a condition (a value in a group)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40692025/how-to-update-column-based-on-a-condition-a-value-in-a-group)

Comment: I do not believe you will gain much by not utilizing `groupByKey`, since you do not seem to be performing some kind of aggregation to drastically reduce the size on the return values (I could be wrong, depends on `isApplicable`).  See, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46823497/7579547) for an answer to a similar question.

Answer (score 1):

GroupByKey should be avoided. Try using reduceByKey instead, it will apply your function on each partition before shuffling your data with the same key.

The less data are shuffled, the better.

Here is a great example https://databricks.gitbooks.io/databricks-spark-knowledge-base/content/best_practices/prefer_reducebykey_over_groupbykey.html